# How to do autofocus for a google web app script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am writing my first Google webapp. I am trying to setup a form with an input but cannot get focus on the first input. Is there some trick to doing autofocus in google webapps? In the following code focus is not given to the input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
     </head> <body>
    <form>
      <h1>Enter Loan Details</h1>
      <br>
      <label for="multiInput">Scan Number / Name or Hardware Tag</label>
      <input type="text" id="multiInput" name="multiInput"  autofocus>
    </form>   </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Focus on element of your choice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
     <label>Your name: </label>
     <input id="first" type="text" size = "25" />
     <script>
       //waits for window to load
       window.onload = function() {
         document.getElementById('first').focus();
       }
     </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

- [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)
- [addMetaTag(name, content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String))
- [getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getTitle())

```
    function showdialog() {
      let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'),Test Dialog')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the scripting solution solves the problem but I still wonder, why did google app script break the autofocus attribute for input.

Comment: There are several things done differently in the HtlmService.  For example HtmlService does not read meta tags in the html file.  Instead you have to use the addMetaTag() method to implement them

Comment: OK, didn't know that either - thanks for the bonus tip.